# Is every subgroup of a group normal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Is there a simple example that can be used to show that not every subgroup of a group is normal?

thanks,

Comment: If every subgroup of every group were normal, there wouldn't be a name for it.

Comment: @MattSamuel Nice heuristic :P

Comment: @MattSamuel, I have edited my question.

Comment: I don't understand your question. No, it is not possible to show that every subgroup of a group is normal, and the reason is that the statement is false.

Comment: Minimal example: take an element $\sigma$ of order two in the group $S_3$ of permutations of three objects. Then the subgroup generated by $\sigma$ is not normal.

Comment: no, it is not, just look at $S_2$ as a subgroup of $S_3$. Edit: egreg was faster

Comment: I think he wants a classification of all groups where all subgroups are normal. The answer to that is [Dedekind groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_group).

Comment: The question you link to isn't concerned with abelian groups.

Comment: In future you may want to show that you've done some work on the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the dihedral group $D_6 = \langle x, y\mid x^3 = 1, y^2 = 1, yx = x^2y\rangle$. $K = \{1,y\}$ is a subgroup which isn't normal. $xKx^{-1} = \{1,xyx^{-1} = xyx^2 = xx^2yx = xx^2x^2y = x^5 y = x^2y\} \not= K$.

Answer (score 0):

It is of course not the case that every subgroup of every group is normal.

If you have a *particular* group in mind, then it may or may not be *true* that all of its subgroups are normal. If it is true, then it may or may not be *provable* that they are.

Whether is is provable depends as much on *which kind of definition* of the group you have that the proof must start from, as it depends on "objective" properties of the group *itself*.